# Assertion failure in +[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:]?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, ccsprite, cgsize

I'm getting an **Assertion failure in +[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:]** for some reason.

I'm basically trying to "updatePinkBerries" or in other words, creating more sprite 'berries' to be added to the screen. They are the 'enemies' in my game.

This is my code:

```
- (id) init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {

        CCLOG(@"%@ init", NSStringFromClass([self class]));

        self.touchEnabled = YES;

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updatePinkBerries:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

    if (curTime > _nextPinkBerrySpawn)
    {
        // Figure out the next time to spawn an asteroid
        float randSecs = randomValueBetween(0.20, 1.0); _nextPinkBerrySpawn = randSecs + curTime;

        // Figure out a random Y value to spawn at
        float randY = randomValueBetween(0.0, winSize.height);

        // Figure out a random amount of time to move from right to left
        float randDuration = randomValueBetween(2.0, 10.0);

        // Create a new asteroid sprite
        CCSprite *pinkBerry = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ship.png"]; [_batchNode addChild:pinkBerry];

        // Set its position to be offscreen to the right
        pinkBerry.position = ccp(winSize.width + pinkBerry.contentSize.width/2, randY);

        // Move it offscreen to the left, and when it's done, call removeNode
        [pinkBerry runAction:
         [CCSequence actions:
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:randDuration position:ccp(-winSize.width- pinkBerry.contentSize.width, 0)],
          [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeNode:)], nil]];
    }
}
```

> EDIT: FULL ASSERTION LOG:
>
> 2013-03-31 19:39:09.225 Berry Muncher-iOS[19550:c07] -[CCFileUtils
>   fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not
>   found: Sprites.plist 2013-03-31 19:39:09.225 Berry
>   Muncher-iOS[19550:c07] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file
>   'Sprites.png' as texture 2013-03-31 19:39:09.425 Berry
>   Muncher-iOS[19550:c07] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'ship.png'
>   not found 2013-03-31 19:39:09.426 Berry Muncher-iOS[19550:c07] ***
>   Assertion failure in +[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:],
>   /Users/Suraya/Desktop/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.1.0/**Kobold2D**/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:105

EDIT: screenshot of my plist

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full assertion log? Usually there's a message explaining the reason it failed.

Comment: Yes definitely I edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a frame called 'ship.png' on your spritesheet? Others frames are loaded with no problems?

Comment: Thats the only frame on there. I'm new to sprite sheets. In the ".plist" I just added a Dictionary called "ship.png".

Comment: How did you create the spritesheet? Usually you'd use a tool like TexturePacker.

Comment: file not found: Sprites.plist. Is the file in your project and added to the correct target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognize this from a Ray Wanderlich tutorial. Because he has different artwork than you might use, you should create your own `CCSpriteBatchNode` and accompanying `plist` file so item names from his project don't get mixed up with yours.

Comment: I created my batch node:     
    _batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"berries-hd.pvr.ccz"]; [self addChild:_batchNode z:-1];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
     addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"berries-hd.plist"];

Comment: It can't find my plist or .ccz but I created them both in Texture Packer. Do you think I'm doing something wrong in Texture Packer?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in Texture Packer? I'm not too familiar with the software, however. It doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong. When I follow Ray Wanderlich tutorials, I like to create my own project in order that my files and code don't get mixed up with his.